# How can i import blender 3d model in after effect

Tags: modeling, import

How can I import a Blender 3d model in After Effects? Is there any work process or plugin that can help me to import a Blender model similar to Cinema 4D lite model?

Thanks,
Simranjit Singh

Answer (score -1):

No, Currently You Can't (According to me)
Currently There is No Live Link Between After Effects and Blender to Directly Import 3d Model in After Effects But You can Export Tracking Data or Other Data from After Effects to Blender and Vice Versa Using Python Scripts 
or You Can Just Import a 3D Model in After Effects Using "Element 3d Plugin For After Effects" But That Needs GPU "Element 3d" Will Not Run On CPU.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE and thank you for your contribution. In fufure, please try to use [punctuation](https://www.julian.com/blog/punctuation) and [capitalization](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/capital.asp). I understand, that this is difficult in a foreing language.